# The data exists on database but the query returns null

Tags: swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

My database structure:

```
Root
    --userRooms
    ----userUid
    ------roomAutoId
    --------receiverId: "wHYI6SFcKKWmY9EXRHutgpru32t1"
    --------senderId: "LKupL7KYiedpr6uEizdCapezJ6"
    --------timestamp: 1485385088055
```

My objective: Query the **userRooms/userUid** and check if **receiverId** selected exists. If yes = keep the **roomAutoId** on completion. If not, keep **""** on completion.

My Code:

```
func queryDatabase(reference: FIRDatabaseReference, variable: String, value: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void){
    print(reference) // https://myproject.firebaseio.com/userRooms/7R9FWwv68IYCEj0Ll18E0aLxHCm1
    print(variable) // receiverId
    print(value) // wHYI6SFcKKWmY9EXRHutgpru32t1
    let queryRef = reference.queryOrdered(byChild: variable).queryEqual(toValue: value)
    queryRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot.value) // Optional(<null>)
        if snapshot.hasChildren() == false{
             completion("")
        }else{
            for snap in snapshot.children {
                let chatSnap = snap as! FIRDataSnapshot
                let chatId = chatSnap.key //the uid of each user
                completion(chatId)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

**Problem: Sometimes snapshot results null, sometimes it get the value.**

Note: Note: The problem seems to happen when i try to query a roomAutoId that i just add. But the problem persists after restart the simulator.

Is there something wrong with the code? Someone can help? Thanks!

Comment: as i know you need to query the firebase at start to get a full data set and later with `observeSingleEvent` you get the change events for each value changed ( https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write )

Comment: @muescha , I don't know if i missunderstood, but did not the code is already doing what you said? **Step 1)** let queryRef = reference.queryOrdered(byChild: variable).queryEqual(toValue: value)  **Step 2 )** queryRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in ...

Comment: I build this structure in my firebase and used almost identical code and it worked 100% of the time. Perhaps there's an async issue with the data being passed in or possibly the completion().

Comment: I think i find out what is going on. The "observeSingleEvent" is getting the query result only once. If I execute the function again the query doesn't get the updated value. I tried use ".observe(FIRDataEventType.value" but the query is automatically triggered again if child value changes, and it is not what I need. **I need a query that is executed every time the function is called, as if running for the first time**. Unfortunately, put the function in viewDidAppear to execute again as in the first time is not working. So i supose that the "observer" seems to be still there

Comment: The .observeSingleEvent will retrieve the value every time its called. It just doesn't leave an observer attached to the node so you would not be notified of future change events, so that's what you want. As I mentioned, I pretty much copy and pasted the code in your question and it works 100% of the time. I can call it 100 times and it works 100 times. The error is elsewhere in your code. I would suggest that perhaps the values being passed into the function are sometimes nil or not populated correctly. Easy to test; use static, known values inside the function and see what happens.

Comment: I removed the **.queryOrdered(byChild: variable).queryEqual(toValue: value)** and the query result with no filter is **Snap (7R9FWwv68IYCEj0Ll18E0aLxHCm1) {
    "-KblNKmZL2jqnUgkbjB8" =     {
        receiverId = nJ86zN6aZQR9DCRIdfniZ1SIPa52;
        senderId = 7R9FWwv68IYCEj0Ll18E0aLxHCm1;
        timestamp = 1485813407075;
    };
    "-KblfGZAIjNN1FD2QRPR" =     {
        receiverId = lViBZLtxT2cbWfo2oErYeLXrSRd2;
        senderId = 7R9FWwv68IYCEj0Ll18E0aLxHCm1;
        timestamp = 1485818370510;
    };
}

Comment: And even using **variable** function parameter as **receiverId** and the **value** parameter as **lViBZLtxT2cbWfo2oErYeLXrSRd2**, the query still results null.

Comment: After no success using ".observeSingleEvent" (sometimes it was returning null) i did several tests using ".observe(.value", removing observer, and it worked as I expected.